# need to join two tables without duplication in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

table1

```
  `s.no | name   |total_price
 ------ | ------ |------------
      1 | kathir |  100'
```

table2

```
  `s.no | rent_name   |rent_price| f_key
 ------ | ------ -----|----------|------
      1 | k1          |  10      | 1
      2 | k2          | 20       | 1
```

my query:

```
select t1.name,t1.total_price,t1.rent_name,t1.rent_price 
from table1 t1 left join   table2 t1 ON t1.s_no=t2.f_key
```

result:

```
    `s.no | name   |total_price| rent_name | rent_price
    ------| -------|-----------|-----------|------
      1   | kathir |  100      | k1        |  10
      2   |kathir  |  100      | k2        |20
```

when i calculate sum of total price of kathir its give me 200 but real is 100 only
expected result:

```
    `s.no | name   |total_price| rent_name | rent_price
    ------| -------|-----------|-----------|------
      1   | kathir |  100      | k1        |  10
      2   |kathir  |   0      | k2        |20
```

if i calculate the sum of total_price of kathir is give me 100 and rent names k1 and k2 and rent price 10,20 and sum is 30..how to achieve this

Comment: Why join table2 if you are not using it in the `select`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I need join two tables one record have two column in postgre sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43021542/i-need-join-two-tables-one-record-have-two-column-in-postgre-sql)

Comment: @lightsouls more like exact duplicate.

Comment: The first result is the one that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try my Edited Answer as below

```
select t2.s_no, t1.name,(case when  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f_key ORDER BY t2.s_no asc)  = 1 then t1.total_price else 0 end) as total_price,t2.rent_name,t2.rent_price 
from table1 t1 left join   table2 t2 ON t1.s_no=t2.f_key
```

Comment: it make all the row price as 0 sumit i want only for kathir one record price is 100 other than that all zero

Answer (score 0):

table1

```
  `s.no | name   |total_price
 ------ | ------ |------------
      1 | kathir |  100
 ------ | ------ |------------
      2 |mani    |  200
```

in table one many records can be there

```
 `s.no | rent_name   |rent_price| f_key
 ------ | ------ -----|----------|------
      1 | k1          |  10      | 1
      2 | k2          | 20       | 1
      3 |k3           | 30       |2
       4|k1            |10        |2
```

select t1.name,t1.total_price,t1.rent_name,t1.rent_price 
    from table1 t1 left join   table2 t1 ON t1.s_no=t2.f_key

expected result:

```
    `s.no | name   |total_price| rent_name | rent_price
    ------| -------|-----------|-----------|------
      1   | kathir |  100      | k1        |  10
      2   |kathir  |  0         | k2       |20
      3   |mani    |200         |k3         |30
       4   |mani    |0          |k1         |10
```

Comment: How is this answer different to your question?

Answer (score 0):

My latest answer. Its working as per your requirement

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as sl_no, t1.name,(case when  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f_key ORDER BY t2.s_no asc)  = 1 or f_key is null then t1.total_price else 0 end) as total_price,t2.rent_name,t2.rent_price 
from table1 t1 left join   table2 t2 ON t1.s_no=t2.f_key
```

Working link for sqlfiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/6cf9d

Comment: If my answer helped you then please accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

table1

```
  `s.no | name   |total_price
 ------ | ------ |------------
      1 | kathir |  100
 ------ | ------ |------------
      2 |mani    |  200
      3  vinoth    300
      4  dinesh    400
```

in table one many records can be there

```
 `s.no | rent_name   |rent_price| f_key
 ------ | ------ -----|----------|------
      1 | k1          |  10      | 1
      2 | k2          | 20       | 1
      3 |k3           | 30       |2
       4|k1            |10        |2
```

select t2.s_no, t1.name,(case when  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY f_key ORDER BY t2.s_no asc)  = 1 then t1.total_price else 0 end) as total_price,t2.rent_name,t2.rent_price 
from table1 t1 left join   table2 t2 ON t1.s_no=t2.f_key

result:

```
    `s.no | name   |total_price| rent_name | rent_price
    ------| -------|-----------|-----------|------
      1   | kathir |  100      | k1        |  10
      2   |kathir  |  0         | k2       |20
      3   |mani    |200         |k3         |30
       4   |mani    |0          |k1         |10
       5     vinoth  | 300
       6     dinesh  |  0
```